# Token not being added to local storage after successful request

Tags: aurelia, aurelia-auth

I'm having trouble with the [aurelia-auth](https://github.com/paulvanbladel/aurelia-auth/) plugin. I can request a token from my back-end and get a successful response - however, my app doesn't appear to be authenticated and no token is saved to local storage.

auth-config.js

```
var config = {

  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:64794',
  signupUrl: 'users',
  loginUrl: 'api/values/PostPassword',
  tokenName: 'id_token',
  loginRedirect: '#/welcome',
  authHeader: 'Authorization',
  authToken: 'Bearer',
  storage: 'localStorage'
}

export default config;
```

login.js

```
import {AuthService} from 'aurelia-auth';
import {inject} from 'aurelia-framework';

@inject(AuthService)

export class Login {

  heading = 'Login';

  email = '';
  password = '';

  loginError = '';

  constructor(auth) {
    this.auth = auth;
  };

  login() {
    return this.auth.login(this.email, this.password)
    .then(response => {
      console.log("Login response: " + response);
      console.log("Auth: " + this.auth.isAuthenticated());
    })
    .catch(error => {
      this.loginError = error.response;
    });
  };
}
```

Console output:

```
Login response: eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1bmlxdWVfbmFtZSI6ImIiLCJuYmYiOjE1MDkyNzkxMzYsImV4cCI6MTUwOTI4MDMzNiwiaWF0IjoxNTA5Mjc5MTM2fQ.4QZu8pQI-K_71x_CKT9ANu1vQD7VvVUcyep51CvvCXg
login.js:27 Auth: false
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

token (or the object containing it) is expected to be the value of prop 'access_token' in the response by default in aurelia-auth

so you need to change the structure of your api response to

```
{ access_token: YOUR_TOKEN }
```

if you have no control over the server, you could still extract the token by overriding the default config. one in question here is `responseTokenProp`, more [here](https://github.com/paulvanbladel/aurelia-auth/#full-configuration-options)

also,  for a clearer picture as to how the token is extracted, have a look [here](https://github.com/paulvanbladel/aurelia-auth/blob/master/src/authentication.js#L66)

Comment: Oh I see what you mean - in my case from my config, should it be `id_token`? Thanks for the reply.